# show the character of string, that user entered. C language

Tags: c, string, find, character

I'd like to ask if it's possible to do something like this:
For example I have a string B with text and I wrote a code like this:

```
puts("Enter the number of character in string B:");

gets(number);
```

I would like that a program would print a character that user has entered. For example

`char B[] = {"Shop"};`

user entered 4 and computer prints p character. I think this should look like:

```
char b[number];

printf("%s", b);
```

But it doesn't work. I hope that you will understand what I want to do. Sorry, for my English. Still learning.

Comment: You can write, `printf("%c", number+(4-1));` to print exact char. In this case 4th char. But this is not correct way.

Comment: just looking at your code does not seem right to me. Your 'number' should be array of char and not an integer value and moreover you can't declare an array with variable length. You either have your array 'b' fix length big enough to store the total characters expected or you use dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((number <= strlen(B)) && (number >= 1))
    printf("%c", B[number - 1]);
else
    printf("Entered number: %d : is out of range\n", number);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! 
Maybie you could answer why you wrote - 1 in ([number - 1]). 
However, it works perfectly!

Comment: In C the array index starts from 0 till (len-1). In your example as you want 'p' to be printed when one gives '4',then the value of 'p' is in B[3].

Answer (score 2):

Regard to Joe`s answer:

Do not forget to check negative value:

```
    if (number <= strlen(B) && unmber>=0)
        printf("%c", B[number - 1]);
    else
        printf("Entered number: %d : is out of range\n", number);
```

Comment: Thansk. I have updated my answer. You could also directly edit my answer too. That way we can avoid duplicate answers in the thread